# Typescript Configuration to disable strict mode check for node_modules content

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor, node-modules

I am using protractor and typescript to write automation test script using "core-framework" node module which is also implemented in protractor and typescript. My automation test scripts are located under **"Projects"** folder. 
Using below typescript configuration I want to perform typescript strict mode check on my project. But it is also performing strict-mode check for used "core-framework" node module.
My requirement is, how to exclude "core-framework" node module from strict mode check.

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "Projects"

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true, /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
  },
  "include": [
    ".\\Projects"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    ".\\node_modules\\core-framework"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile with --noImplicitUseStrict compiler option

Add below line

```
"noImplicitUseStrict": true
```

to "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mitul. I have already tried this option, along with other options like,                                                                                                  
    `"noUnusedLocals": true, /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */`           
   and it checks for the same on entire project including node_modules which i do not want to check for the strict mode. I only want to check strict mode for my test scripts.